# Trouble with urldecode and fetching information from database

Tags: php, sql, urldecode

I have used `urldecode` to receive a member ID from a previous site. The correct ID is being displayed in the URL but I can't fetch information from the database.

```
<?php

$id = urldecode(trim($_GET['memberID']));
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberID = '".$id."'";

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["memberID"], $row['name']);
}
}

?>
```

All I get is a blank screen.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I have now updated it.

Answer (score 1):

change `mysql.error()` to `mysql_error()`

Answer (score -1):

$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberID = '".$id."'";